# What is the regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm using Nltk's punkt tokenizer to tokenize a paragraph into sentences, but in some scenarios like the examples below, tokenizer is not able to identify the sentences as the period is followed by numbers. I want to identify these scenarios using a regular expression and replace `'.1,7,9'` with `'. 1,7,9'` i.e add space between the citations and period.

```
Ex1.  `This is a random sentence.1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it.`
Ex2. I love football.1,7,24`I also like cricket.

Ex3. ESD for undifferentiated  cancers.[1][7]`Cancers can be treatable.
```

Expected output:

```
EX1. This is a random sentence.
     1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it.
Ex2. I love football.
     ESD for undifferentiated  cancers.1,7
Ex3. ESD for undifferentiated  cancers.1,7
     [1][7]`Cancers can be treatable.
```

Thank you.

Comment: what's your expected output for the 3rd case?

Comment: your third example and expected output is different.

Comment: sorry my bad. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would replace all the dots follwed by a non-space character with `.` + `\n`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Ex1.  This is a random sentence.1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it."
>>> print(re.sub(r'\.(\S)', r'.\n\1', s))
Ex1.  This is a random sentence.
1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it.
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/5)

Comment: Give me a minute I will test it and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks (+1) for the nice DEMO link.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  Your regex is working fine for the above examples. But if there is a email ID 'ask@to.in' It is dividing it into 'ask@to' and 'in' ,also if there is decimal number like '1.3704' its dividing it into 1 and 3704.
What I was trying to acheive is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362160/how-can-we-remove-citations-in-a-word-document-using-python

Comment: so how do i differentiate?

Comment: I have accepted your answer.  I'm asking you for any leads on solving my problem. Basically all I have to do is remove the superscripts after a period.

Comment: could you provide some examples (which satisfies all your needs) along with the expected output in this https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/6 link?

Comment: I will compile all the scenarios and paste it there. Thank you so much for the effort.

Comment: I have pasted some of the scenarios here https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/8. What do you think is best? Compiling a regex or to somehow remove the superscripts after a period before reading the data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the appended integer list is a reference, it may be useful to place the character return after the integer list:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Ex1.  This is a random sentence.1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it."
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\.\S+\s)', r'\1\n', s))
Ex1.  This is a random sentence.1,7,9 
This is a sentence followed by it.
```

Comment: But the tokenizer I'm using is not able to distinguish between a new sentence if there is no space after a period. How can we add space in your regex ?

Comment: you mean this `print(re.sub(r'\.(\S)', r'. \1', s))`

Comment: @AvinashRaj What should we do to get output like this :" This is a random sentence. 1,7,9 This is a sentence followed by it." #space after the period.
If this is the scenario then the tokenizer is able to distinguish two different sentences.

Comment: @ask13704804 it's better to ask it as a new question.

Comment: I'm not allowed to ask a new question for another 3 days as I got 2 downvotes for my previous question and I recently joined. My reputation is only 8. Can please do something here?